# button lost after video go full screen

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a button called `record-media` which was put in front of a video(video and button are siblings) and show when users hoving mouse on it. However, when the video goes full screen, the button was lost. This is function toggle the video:

```
toggleFullScreen() {
    let video = document.querySelector('video')

    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
    } else {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

and this is my css:

```
.record-media {
  z-index: 1;
  top: -75px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

What was I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common container for video element and the button itself. And then make that element go full-screen.

Something like this - `<div class="video-container"><video/>
<button class="record-media">Some-button</button></div>`

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Comment: I got problem when opening full-screen, in normal case button still showed

Comment: It is required in this case for the button to be inside the element being shown in fullscreen. 

Above code setup indicated that video tag is being `.requestFullscreen()`-ed and effectively will include it and all it's descendants in the fullscreen, but not any sibling. And `.record-media` seems to be a sibling to video.

Comment: exactly, they are siblings. This is the point, I fixed it by wrapping two of them in to a div. Thank you.

Comment: @DinhNgocHien - then you might want to select this as right answer. And welcome.